# WhatsApp Template with Header and Dynamic Button

Tags: twilio

I would like to add a dynamic button with parameter for WhatsApp template on Twilio.

For example:

[image]

This WhatsApp template have header, footer and dynamic button. I want to use the templat like this on Twilio. How should i create a template like this on Twilio?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be defined in the message template.

You can't change the reply text (text that get's filled when user clicks the button) dynamically when making requests.

You can only change payload (the value that comes with webhook data)